# Need a docker-compose for installing elastic search and kibana with password for kibana, for ELK stack version 8

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: es-container
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.11.0
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
    volumes:
      - ./esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - es-net
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
  kibana:
    container_name: kb-container
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.11.0
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://es-container:9200
    networks:
      - es-net
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    volumes:
      - kibanadata:/usr/share/kibana/data
networks:
  es-net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  esdata:
    driver: local
  kibanadata:
    driver: local
```

This doesn't run ES in a cluster or have a password enabled, Also I need a version of 8, when I try that I get an error connecting kibana with ES.

Can some help me with a working docker-compose.yaml

Answer (score 5):

Best thing to do is to use template here: [docker-elk](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk).

Then you can read documentation and find what exactly is happening here. It is pretty awesome repo and help you master elk without much in-depth explore in docker.

Answer (score 2):

With 8.x where security is enabled by default this is a little more complicated, but the documentation has a fully working example: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.3/docker.html#docker-compose-file

Replace `8.3` with the version you are trying to set up and it will give you a working configuration.